# reserved characters like dollar and - are not working in in regex- angular2

Tags: angular

I want a regex which allows alphabets, numbers and some special characters like /$:-*@.
for this I tried regex pattern
"^[ A-Za-z0-9*@.$/-:]*$"
this works fine for all other conditions but with dollar and - this fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using the regex?

Comment: <input [ngControl]="abc" pattern="^[ A-Za-z0-9\$_@./-:]*$"> like this.

Comment: The only error I see is that you have to escape the range character `-` -> `\-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"^[ A-Za-z0-9@.$/\-:]*$"`

In regex '-' is a special character, which you have to escape.
Dollar sign works here:
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/80aDnQ/3)

Comment: Why is the dollar sign special? The minus sign is special, because it is interpreted as a range character when used inside brackets.

Comment: @Silvermind It marks the end of the string.

Comment: Not inside the brackets.

Comment: @Silvermind Not inside the brackets. -- it is still a Regex special char

Comment: @Silvermind that is true, edited my answer.

Comment: @noririco Only outside the brackets. This is perfectly valid: `^[ A-Za-z0-9@.$/\-:]*$`

Comment: @Silvermind - this worked well for - and $ can you help me edit this to make atleast 1 character compulsory

Comment: @dev Make the asterisk symbol (*) a plus symbol (+).